# Remove top line of output PowerShell

Tags: php, arrays, windows, powershell

I am trying to get the session ID but the below output is giving me the ID column name. If I use match it gives me the correct value as the output doesn't seem to have the column names in.

How do I remove the top line so I can just get the IDs value?

```
$sessionID = ( (quser | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'username' } ) -split ' +')[3]

logoff $sessionID
```

Comment: Is the `Where-Object` statement supposed to remove the first line? Or is it an attempt at filtering out a specific user?

Comment: You can simplify this by using this function: [Get-QUser](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/5014-get-quser). Turns `QUser.exe` results into an object you can work with so you can do something like: `$sessionID = Get-QUser`, and then reference the ID(s) `$sessionID.ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your usernames contain no spaces (if they did, it would be highly unusual):

To get the ID of the *first* user session listed by `quser`:

```
(-split (quser)[1])[2]
```

To get *all* user-session IDs:

```
quser | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { (-split $_)[2] }
```

Cast to `[int] (...)` / `[int[]] (...)` if you want the extracted IDs to be *numbers*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

The only immediate problem with your approach was use of index `[3]` instead of `[2]` - since array indices are `0`-based, `[2]` is needed to retrieve the *3rd* element, which is the `Id` field.

However, instead of using a `-match` operation to skip the header line, it is easier to simply skip the *first* line, as shown above:

- `(quser)[1]` returns the *second* line only, i.e. the first *data* line.
- Similarly, `Select-Object -Skip 1` skips the first input object, i.e. the header line (PowerShell streams the (stdout) output from external programs line by line).

The *unary* form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), as used at the top, is a convenient way to split by nonempty runs of whitespace (ignoring leading and trailing whitespace).

Comment: Thanks I used 
`((quser | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'username' } | Select-Object -Skip 1)-split ' +')[2]`